# probability of a random walk entering an area?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

How would you go about finding the probability of a particle located at $x_p$ with stochastic mobility (at each time step it moves at a random direction with a random speed, $v_{\mbox{speed}}$, lets sat both uniformly distributed), entering a spherical area centered at $x_c$ and radius $r_c$ after $N$ time steps?

Comment: With no time step cap, this can in principle be handled by solving a Backward Kolmogorov equation; you can look up references on renewal theory to see how to set this up. With the time step cap, you can technically do the same thing by expanding the state space by one more dimension and then introducing an additional boundary at the terminal time (which you interpret as "failure"). The discrete time character of the problem creates a bit of difficulty with analysis, because the particle won't hit the boundary at a discrete time.

Comment: "after $N$ time steps" means that a time $N$ the particle is inside the sphere? or that it precisely enters the sphere at that time? or that it enters the sphere at $N$ or less steps?

Comment: @leonbloy "enters the sphere at  or less steps"